# How to elegantly compare zip folder contents to unzipped folder contents

Tags: python, zip, backup, unzip

This is the scenario. I want to be able to backup the contents of a folder using a python script. However, I want my backups to be stored in a zipped format, possibly bz2.

The problem comes from the fact that I don’t want to bother backing up the folder if the contents in the “current” folder are exactly the same as what is in my most recent backup.

My process will be like this:

1. Initiate backup
2. Check contents of “current” folder against what is stored in the most recent zipped backup
3. If same – then “complete”
4. If different, then run backup, then “complete”

Can anyone recomment the most reliable and simple way of completing step2? Do I have to unzip the contents of the backup and store in a temp directory to do a comparison or is there a more elegant way of doing this? Possibly to do with modified date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zip files contain CRC32 checksums and you can read them with the python zipfile module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html. You can get a list of ZipInfo objects with CRC members from ZipFile.infolist(). There are also modification dates in the ZipInfo object.

You can compare the zip checksum with calculated checksums for the unpacked files. You need to read the unpacked files but you avoid having to decompress everything.

CRC32 is not a cryptographic checksum but it should be enough if all you need is to check for changes.

This holds for zip files. Other archive formats (like tar.bz2) might not contain such easily-accessible metadata.

Comment: This is a good idea. You would have to read all the files again, but it would save you the writes.

Answer (score 2):

I use this script to create compress backup of a directory
only when the directory contents has changed after last backup.

I use external md5 file to store the digest of the backup file and I check
it to detect directory changes.

```
import hashlib
import tarfile
import bz2
import cStringIO
import os

def backup_dir(dirname, backup_path):
    fobj = cStringIO.StringIO()
    t = tarfile.open(mode='w',fileobj=fobj)
    t.add(dirname)
    t.close()
    buf = fobj.getvalue()
    new_md5 = hashlib.md5(buf).digest()

    if os.path.isfile(backup_path + '.md5'):
        old_md5 = open(backup_path + '.md5').read()
    else:
        old_md5 = ''

    if new_md5 <> old_md5:
        open(backup_path, 'wb').write(bz2.compress(buf))
        open(backup_path + '.md5', 'wb').write(new_md5)
        print 'backup done!'
    else:
        print 'nothing to do'
```

Comment: How is this upvoted, this has a syntax error

Comment: This is from 2012, it was using python 2.7

Comment: I don't remember `<>` being a comparision operator? Did I miss something?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Rsync will automatically detect and only copy modified files, but seeing as you want to bzip the results, you still need to detect if anything has changed.

How about you output the directory listing (including time stamps) to a text file alongside your archive. The next time you `diff` the current directory structure against this stored text. You can grep differences out and pipe this file list to rsync to `include` those changed files.

Comment: Is there a way to check the timestamp of a file in an archive without having to extract the contents from the archive? That way I could avoid the file.

Comment: Check if your bzip `list archive contents` action shows modified time. If it does not, consider storing the time of your last archive in a file, and check against that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the following process:

1) Initiate backup

2) Run backup

3) Compare both compressed files:

```
import filecmp
filecmp.cmp(Compressed_new_file, Compressed_old_file, shallow=True)
```

4) If same – delete new backup file then "complete"

5) Else “complete”

NOTE: In case you need to check just the time between the modifications, you can have a look at [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat)

Rather than decompressing the folder and comparing individual files, I think it might be easier to compare the compressed files.
Overall I feel (ok, its just an intuition :D) this will be better in case there is a high probability that the contents of the folder changes in between the times you run the script